# Change in internal chemical potential of electrons in the 2DEG

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, chemical-potential, density-of-states

I was reading about [quantum capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_capacitance) and came across the following formula:

$$\Delta \mu = \frac{N}{\rho}$$ where N is the number of electrons moved from the metal to the low-density-of-states material, and $\rho$ is the density of states of the low-density-of-states material.

I am having a hard time understanding where this formula came from.

If someone could point me to a reference or derivation, I would appreciate it.